# py2exe reports paramiko missing

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm having a problem with py2exe not finding paramiko.

Environment is Windows 7 / Python 2.7

Here is the simple test (called test2.py):

```
# Test file for py2exe

import sys
import os
import paramiko

print "This is a test"
```

And here is my 'setup.py' file:

```
#
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['test2.py'])
```

When I try and build the *.exe:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['paramiko']
```

I do not have a paramiko folder in /lib/site-packages.  Is that possibly my problem?

Comment: Whats' the output of `import paramiko;print(paramiko.__file__)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed paramiko on your Windows system?

http://vijaymurthy.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/installing-paramiko-for-windows/

Comment: Paramiko is installed and the 'real' program operates as expected. The test program reproduces the issue without including all the extraneous 'trash'

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is that you have your **setup.py** in the *same directory* as your module and your are running it from *that directory*.

If that doesn't work your should add your module to your path in **setup.py**:

```
module_path = r'path\to\your\paramiko\module'
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(modules_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

py2exe can not handle zipped site package. Is your paramiko in an egg (essentially zip) file?